# AWS Lambda - How to import from (python) files from the main project repository

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, python-import

***Note: This question is not about automatic install of libraries/packages***

We have a main Python(3) application with all the settings, all the utils, all the enums, models etc.

Then we have an (Amazon) AWS Lambda that digests outside input requests which uses 2 databases and some enums & models from the main app so same restrictions, settings and values would apply.

Now we of course could do the similar thing as it's done with packages and just copy in all the files/folders to match the main app structure to use them (manually).

However that is obviously very unhandy since the main app is interconnected along a larger directory tree. We were searching the Internet and all we could find was always related to automated package/library includes, or reading files from S3.

**Is there a way how to either:**

**A.** Automatically add the whole import tree (recursively of course) in the serverless packaging system? (or at least generate it through some reliable tool separately so it could be added later?)

**B.** Link somehow some repository (?S3? ?EC2?) that contains the main app files to lambda so when someone does e.g. `from modules.database import init_db` in the `lambda_function.py` it would be actually imported even though `modules` resides elswhere?

Comment: Maybe try deploying the library as a layer with it’s own deployment pipeline?

Comment: @HimanshuPant What library? O.o, can you please elaborate on the layer? thank you

Comment: sorry did the late response, From what I can see, you have a local library or module of sorts and you want to deploy it separately, in that case you should deploy the lib/module as an aws lambda layer instead. That’s pretty much all I can say with what I understand so far. Maybe we can chat over this in detail or I can help out on GitHub to understand better

Comment: @HimanshuPant Well the lambda_fuction.py is supposed to be deployed separately as an AWS Lambda, but it uses lot of stuff from all around the code base, so far we're just copying almost the whole code  base, but we were wondering whether serverless has not some automated cherry pick based on the imports. (we have a script that does that). Is this what you're referring to? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about, you can automate the whole process, we have a similar situation but we use webpack so it takes care of bundling for us, I think you could put the rest of your codebase in a layer and simply import from it

Comment: @HimanshuPant OK, that doesn't really answer the question, but it's a definitely a good suggestion ! I shall certainly consider it :-) thank you